# iPhone visualizing math pattern

Tags: iphone, math, design-patterns, visualize

I'm toying with an app idea for the iPhone but I don't know where to start or even what to look for in google :) I'd like to visualize math patterns on the iPhone, similar to this http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/patterns-lite/id304565312?mt=8 ... If someone could point me into the right direction then that would be fantastic. Originally, I had the idea of plotting the math pixel by pixel onto a texture but I think I'm way off. Thanks, Carl.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to subscribe to the iTunes University lecture series: iPhone Application Development (Winter 2010) podcast here:
[link text](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225)

Watch **Lecture 5. Views, Drawing, and Animation (January 19, 2010)**

That will show you how to draw and plot to the screen. The basic drawing model on iPhone is path-based (as opposed to pixel-based) so that's where you should start.